# Splitting a datetime, python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

Sorry I am new to asking questions on stackoverflow so I don't understand how to format properly.

So I'm given a Pandas dataframe that contains column of datetime which contains the date and the time and an associated column that contains some sort of value. The given dates and times are incremented by the hour. I would like to manipulate the dataframe to have them increment every 15 minutes, but retain the same value. How would I do that? Thanks!

I have tried :

`df = df.asfreq('15Min',method='ffill')`.

But I get a error:

> "TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'long'"

current dataframe:

```
datetime     value  
00:00:00     1  
01:00:00     2
```

new dataframe:

```
datetime     value  
00:00:00     1  
00:15:00     1  
00:30:00     1  
00:45:00     1  
01:00:00     2    
01:15:00     2  
01:30:00     2  
01:45:00     2
```

Update:
The approved answer below works, but so does the initial code I tried above 
 `df = df.asfreq('15Min',method='ffill')`. I was messing around with other Dataframes and I seemed to be having trouble with some null values so I took care of that with a fillna statements and everything worked.

Comment: I am sorry the question is not clear enough for me. What do you mean with "to have them increment"? You want to split your rows into smaller units?

Comment: Yes, I have tried df = df.asfreq('15Min',method='ffill'). But I get a "TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'long'"

Comment: @tsbeginner - What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: datetime is datetime64[ns] and value is float64

Comment: @tsbeginner - I ask something different, `print (df.info())` return more info as `datetime is datetime64[ns] and value is float64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`TimedeltaIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html), but is necessary manually add last value for correct [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
tr = pd.timedelta_range(df.index.min(), 
                        df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(45*60, unit='s'), freq='15Min')
df = df.reindex(tr, method='ffill')
print (df)
          value
00:00:00      1
00:15:00      1
00:30:00      1
00:45:00      1
01:00:00      2
01:15:00      2
01:30:00      2
01:45:00      2
```

Another solution with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and same problem - need append new value for correct appending last values:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.loc[df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='h')] = 1

df = df.resample('15Min').ffill().iloc[:-1]
print (df)
          value
datetime       
00:00:00      1
00:15:00      1
00:30:00      1
00:45:00      1
01:00:00      2
01:15:00      2
01:30:00      2
01:45:00      2
```

But if values are datetimes:

```
print (df)
              datetime  value
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00      1
1  2018-01-01 01:00:00      2

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
tr = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), 
                   df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(45*60, unit='s'), freq='15Min')
df = df.reindex(tr, method='ffill')
```

---

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.loc[df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='h')] = 1

df = df.resample('15Min').ffill().iloc[:-1]
print (df)

                     value
datetime                  
2018-01-01 00:00:00      1
2018-01-01 00:15:00      1
2018-01-01 00:30:00      1
2018-01-01 00:45:00      1
2018-01-01 01:00:00      2
2018-01-01 01:15:00      2
2018-01-01 01:30:00      2
2018-01-01 01:45:00      2
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.int64' and 'Timedelta'. For if my values are datetimes.

Comment: @tsbeginner - Please check comment under question.

Comment: @tsbeginner - It seems need check last 2 paragraphs of answer, mainly dont forget for `df = df.set_index('datetime')`

Comment: Ok, so after `df = df.set_index('datetime')` what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: the same as before, datetime is datetime64 and value is float64

Comment: @tsbeginner, I dont believe you get for `print (df.index)`  values `datetime64 `

Comment: I apologize I was having some difficulties with the null values and I figured it out. Your solution is working!

Comment: df = df.asfreq('15Min',method='ffill') worked just the same

Comment: @tsbeginner - Unfortuntaly not, check last rows - missing 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.daterange

```
pd.date_range('00:00:00', '01:00:00', freq='15T')
```